# C# Display Array Items in Windows Form Application

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms

I've added an array that's split to show name and a number and I've outputted those in their own respective individual areas but I want to output every entry in the array to 1 list that shows the inputted names and name (they're entered at the same time)

Most of the questions I've found on here are dealing with outputting the array into Console but I'm using a Windows Form Application so can I output them to a multi-line textbox?

```
public void AddPlayer(string input) 
{ 
   string[] addingPlayer = input.Split(); 
   playerNames[value] = addingPlayer[0]; 
   playerScores[value] = int.Parse(addingPlayer[1]); 
   value++; 
}
```

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: Are you looking for a part in specific? It's using 2 classes, one for GUI process and the other for business logic. All of that is working fine, I just need to output all of the elements in an array.

Comment: `public void AddPlayer(string input)
        {
            string[] addingPlayer = input.Split();
            playerNames[value] = addingPlayer[0];
            playerScores[value] = int.Parse(addingPlayer[1]);
            value++;
        }`

Comment: Grouped arrays are an anti-pattern. You should have a `Player` class with `Name` and `Score` properties.

Comment: I'm not sure that I follow?

Answer (score 4):

Grouped arrays (when you have multiple arrays that are related by index) are an [anti-pattern](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jonskeet/2014/06/03/anti-pattern-parallel-collections/). Don't do that. Instead, you should have a `Player` class with `Name` and `Score` properties:

```
public class Player
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int Score {get;set;}
}
```

Additionally, whenever you have an array that grows, as implied by the need for an `AddPlayer()` function, you should use a *Collection* type like `List<Player>` instead:

```
List<Player> players = new List<Player>();
```

Now your `AddPlayer()` method will look like this:

```
public void AddPlayer(string input) 
{ 
   string[] addingPlayer = input.Split(); 
   players.Add(new Player(){Name = addingPlayer[0], Score = int.Parse(addingPlayer[1])});
}
```

To write the contents of the `players` list to a mutli-line textbox, you could then do this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (Player p in players) 
{
    sb.AppendFormat("{0} - {1}\n", p.Name, p.Score);
}
MyTextBox.Text = sb.ToString();
```